# Duplicating and moving an object by a certain amount in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to duplicate an object by a certain (integer) amount and move it by that x-0.2 (so the first one would be -0.2, second would be -0.4, third would be -0.6). When I try to do this I get the error "Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable".
My code:

```cs
public GameObject object;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    GameObject[] clones = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < GameManager.singleton.currentLevel; i++)
    {
        clones[i] = GameObject.Instantiate(object);
        clones[i].transform.position.y = -0.2 * (i + 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Transform.translate to move the clone. The docs for this can be found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.World.html

You could also set the transform.position to a new vector3 like in this example: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

You get this error because you cannot directly set the x, y and z values of transform.position (I believe that they are read only) but you can set transform.position to a new vector3

This may also help to explain it: https://answers.unity.com/questions/656129/c-changing-the-x-and-y-values-of-a-gameobject.html

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gWb7yxB5 I tried that and it gave me the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line 12. What's causing this?

Comment: Is the object that you are copying null? If so it’s possible that is the issue. Line 12 is a close bracket in the pastebin, so I don’t know exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 6.

Comment: @Dolphin, in that case, it seems that something with your GameManager thing is not instantiated/null. If you want to try something else, you could replace the array with a list(this way you don’t have to define size), although this would be less efficient and a poor programming practice seeing as you do not need dynamic size.

Comment: Actually, I think I know what happened. I used the Awake() method for this, so it got called before the GameManager.

Answer (score 0):

Entering a `null` value in a variable does not define an array. In this case you have no array to configure its members. `object` itself is also a reserved word in C# and you can not use it as a variable name. To solve the problem, change the code as below.

```cs
public GameObject obj;

void Awake()
{
    var clones = new GameObject[GameManager.singleton.currentLevel];
    for (int i = 0; i < clones.Length; i++)
    {
        clones[i] = GameObject.Instantiate(obj);

        var pos = clones[i].transform.position;
        pos.y = -0.2f * (i + 1);
        clones[i].transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: "object" was simply a placeholder name; the name is different in my code.

Comment: @Dolphin There were two other problems with your code. One defines an empty array and the other sets the `position.y` directly. Solve them both, hopefully your problem will be solved.